# Center multiple images horizontally in CSS

Tags: css, image, center

I know this question is very popular, but I couldn't find any elegant answer.

I need to align horizontally 2 images and center them. I've already read about `inline-block` and I pretty good at margins (margin 0 auto trick), paddings and other geometrics. The thing is... that my html code is parsed from markdown by javascript parser (not mine and complex) and each element enclosed into `<p>` tag. But my `text-align` for `<p>` tag is justified.

I understand that answer on my question is to use `<div>` right in markdown around images and set its text-align to center, but I seek for more elegant way to do it because I prefer clean and modern coding with html5 semantics and look into the future where `<div>` elements would be no more.

Basically, my question is simple: is it possible at all to do such a thing without outside block?

### UPD: jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8274L7wc/

It'd be perfect if I could change style of `<p>` based on child element `<img>`, but as far as I know - this is impossible by css.

Also I suppose I could use CSS `calc()` method to calculate width and set precise margins, but I think even `div` would be better than this.

I **can't** use `text-align:center` on `<p>` element because it would make everything centered, not only images.

### UPD2:

I've made quick temporary solution by using jquery `.parents` method to set all `<p>` which contain `<img>` tag - centered:

```
$('img').parents('p').css('text-align', 'center');
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant html structure and css? And a jsfiddle would be awesome :)

Comment: @web-tiki js does not set text-align:justify, it wraps <p> around all elements. justify is set by me.

Comment: @xec, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8274L7wc/

Comment: Thanks for the demo, perfect :) What's the reason you can't set `text-align: center;` on the `<p>`? http://jsfiddle.net/8274L7wc/1/

Comment: @xec `<p>` is generated by javascript markdown parser from md to html and it wraps around all elements. This would make all text to be centered (which I need to be justified).

Comment: Ok, with the restrictions you describe, there is no elegant way to do this except what you already describe yourself: just wrap the images in a `<div>` with `text-align: center;` like you suggested.

Comment: @xec yet, there's `calc()` function way. I suppose it's better to write one big `calc()` function for all images within <p> element than to manually enclose each image from markdown file in `<div>` tag. So I'm gonna at least try to construct needed style using `calc()` function; it seems it won't be as complex as I thought assuming from @Mercurio answer.

Comment: Does the parent (or grand parent) element of `p` tags have an id or class?

Comment: @SalmanA no, it doesn't, but I can add it. But even if it does have id/class, the same id/class would have all elements and so it's no use.

Anyway, I've made quick temporary solution by using jquery `.parents` method to set all `<p>` which contain `<img>` tag - centered.

Comment: Just add an id/class to the parent and use a selector such as `#has-js-generated-content p { text-align: center; }`

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of answers that you might find useful.

**FIRST**

There is a general rule in web development that says you should always try to use basic browsers' functions before relying on CSS. This is part of what we call **progressive enhancement**. Following this rule, the best way to solve your problem is by adding the **html5 element** `<figure></figure>`. [Here is the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) and below is an example using your jsfiddle:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
figure { /* Then you can center your img inside the figure element */
  text-align: center;
}
img { /* You don't need margin 0 auto or display block, let the browser do its work */
  width: 6.25em;
  height: 6.25em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <figure> <!-- You can add several img in a figure element -->
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70091792/Pages/2/workspace2.png" alt="First workspace" title="" />
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70091792/Pages/2/workspace2.png" alt="Web-browser on the second workspace" title="" />
  </figure>
</p>
```

**SECOND**

If you don't want to add an element to your HTML markup then CSS can only help you if you now how many images you will have and what will be their size. In this case you can calculate with `calc()` the dimensions needed and add a padding-left on first image. As you can see this is quite complicated, hard to maintain and definitely not considered as best practices. Here is an example:

```css
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
p img:first-child {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px)
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70091792/Pages/2/workspace2.png" alt="First workspace" title="" />
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70091792/Pages/2/workspace2.png" alt="Web-browser on the second workspace" title="" />
</p>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, if you have **MARKDOWN -> HTML** java/jquery parser on your mind which does **NOT** adds `<p>` everywhere - please give me a link :)

And yes, my parser is very **dirty** and it's not mine.

Comment: I know, this is quite frustrating ;)! That's why I've said I can understand you don't have the choice ;)!

Comment: well, I guess the only way to make it all elegant and working is to write my own markdown parser with blackjack and whores. I want 1/2/3 images and I don't want to mess with html (basically because I'm writing posts in markdown and this would mean that I should write html tag around each image).

Comment: Well these are the only way with CSS / HTML. I don't know enough about markdown parser to help you but I definitely think that you should try to develop a markdown parser that will not add `<p>` tags. By the way you should read Stackoverflow's rules before voting down for an answer, here is what it says: *Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect*. People here are trying to help you for free, don't forget that.

Comment: @jbutler483 Which browser are you using? Check this fiddle and resize your browser, it works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2v651sjz/

Comment: Chrome (V38). Since you're setting your image size in `px`, and then using `%`s, it means that (A) making the screen smaller lengthens your first child, wrapping the second below, and (B) adding new content would be difficult as you'd have to go back to your css. But i have to agree, anything parsing a `<p>` tag unnecessarily should be avoided.

Comment: You are right, it's `margin` and not `padding` that should be used. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

```
<p>
    <img src="http://leone.ge/mem/img/image2.png" />
    <img src="http://leone.ge/mem/img/image2.png" />
</p>

---- 
p{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    background:tan;
    text-align:center
}
p img{
    display:inline-block
}
```

view result here: http://jsfiddle.net/kr76uu46/2/

Comment: I can't use `text-align:center` on `<p>` element, because it would make everything centered, not only images.

Answer (score -1):

Here there are 7 css ways to center *horizontally* and *vertically* an element in the middle of a div (or a body). Than you can create a second div and you get your solution.

1. text-align:center
2. margin:auto
3. display:table-cell
4. position:absolute
5. translate function
6. flexbox
7. **calc function**

```css
img{
width: 100%;
max-width: 150px; //your width
height: auto;
position: relative;
left: calc(25%);
}
```

```html
<img id="b" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Sample Image 6">
<img id="a" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="Sample Image 6">
```

Otherwise, if you are still interesting looking for different ways (css-based solution) check this [LINK](http://umabelstudio.com/centerelement.html)

Comment: This doesn't work, and I don't know why you expected `left: calc(25%);` to center anything. Click **Run code snippet** and then **full screen** and you'll see that the images are not centered.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try `calc()` function for starters.

Comment: @xec, well, obviously `calc()` function would be slightly more complex, including window/document width properties; and for my case I need to take into account possibilities with at least {1,2,3} images.

Comment: How will your css know that an image has two images following it? This looks like a recipe for disaster ;)

Comment: @xec, yep :) well, I've made temporarily jquery solution for now as I use this lib anyway.